# Differential equation with constant RHS

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I feel very dumb asking this, I’ve run into something like this, I’m really confused:

$$xdx=a\,,$$

where $a$ is a constant. Does this have a solution, and if so, how do I approach the problem?

Comment: It's a separable equation, so you can just integrate both sides.

Comment: I don't understand "$xdx$".  Is "$x \cdot x'$" intended?

Answer (score 0):

What you have written does not make sense.  If you have a differential $dx$, conceptually it is a "very tiny change" in $x$.  So you are writing something like "tiny = 3" which makes no sense.  Whenever you have a $d$ on the left, you must also have a $d$ on the right.